# htaccess redirecting sub-domain to domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've been reading a few topics on htaccess redirecting but can't really see anything that will work for me!

I've just redone my WP site and I don't use the sub-domain anymore but I need to keep all the articles.

How do I redirect this to that without get broken links?

Old:
http://blog.name.com/wordpress/2008/05/article01/

New:
http://www.name.com/blog/2008/05/article01/

I am using this already but this does not work with direct links.

`RewriteCond %{http_host} ^blog.rimagine.com/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rimagine.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]`

Anyone know how to ??

Answer (score 0):

Just use the RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.rimagine.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for getting back but this is not really working for what i want. 'http://blog.rimagine.com/wordpress/2008/05/furniture-photography-for-argington/' the redirects dont work on this !